# Calculate $H= \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x^n}dx, \, n>2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, gamma-function, beta-function

Calculate the following integral: $H=\displaystyle \int \limits_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1+x^n}dx, \, n>2$

I wanna use Beta function $B(x,y)=\displaystyle \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}}dt, \,x,y>0$. As follows,

Set $x^n=t \Rightarrow x=t^{\tfrac{1}{n}}\Rightarrow dx=\dfrac{t^{\tfrac{1}{n}-1}}{n}dt$

\begin{align*}
H&=\displaystyle \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{t^{\tfrac{1}{n}+1}}{1+t}.\frac{t^{\tfrac{1}{n}-1}}{n}dt\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{t^\tfrac{2}{n}}{1+t}dt
\end{align*}
So, $x=\frac{2}{n}+1 >0$ and $y=-\frac{2}{n}<0.$ So, cann't use Beta function.

Comment: Easy to see this integral diverges, so no need to compute.

Comment: ^ it's essentially like integrating $\int_0^{\infty}x\,dx=\infty$.

Comment: Oh, i thought everything complex. Thank guys.

Comment: Since $\frac{x^{n}}{1+x^n}x=\big(1-\frac{1}{1+x^n}\big)x\geq \big(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\big)x\mathbb{1}_{[2,\infty]}$, and $\int^\infty_2 x\,dx=\infty$, your integral is diverges to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $\text{deg}\left(x^{n+1}\right)>\text{deg}\left(1+x^{n}\right)$, so $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x^n}=\infty$. This implies that there is a positive number $N$ such that $\frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x^n}>1$ for all $x>N$.

It's clear that the integral

$$\int_{N}^{\infty}1\text{ }dx$$

diverges, so $\int_{N}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x^n}dx$ diverges by comparison. It follows that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x^n}dx$ is also divergent.

Answer (score 1):

The given integral diverges. See
$$H=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1} dx}{1+x^n} \sim \int_{0}^{\infty} x dx \rightarrow \infty$$